# Tkinter optionmenu taking up more space than its containing frame in windows, but not linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, tkinter

I was working on a tkinter UI on my linux box over the weekend, and got it working mostly the way I wanted.  Now I'm trying the same code on windows and it's working differently.
What I'm trying to do is place a frame exactly over the top of part of another widget (using place), which works great on both systems.  I'm then trying to put an OptionMenu widget in that frame, and have it fill the whole frame.
This works great in Linux, but on Windows, the frame resizes around the optionmenu, so it no longer the specified size, it's taller and narrower than the specified frame.  Here is some example code that shows the problem:

```
from Tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
frame1=Frame(tk, height=200, width = 200, bd=1)
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH)
marker=Frame(frame1, height=20, width=100, bd=2, bg='#55FF55')
marker.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.5)
frame2=Frame(frame1, height=20, width=100, bd=2, bg='#FF5555')
frame2.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.5)
var=StringVar(frame2)
om=OptionMenu(frame2, var, 'One', 'Two', 'Three')
om.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Any idea how I can get the OptionMenu to fill but not exceed the original frame size?

Comment: What do you consider "the original frame"? What size are you trying to constrain it to? What are you actually trying to accomplish? This is a very strange bit of code. There might be  a better way to do what you want.

Comment: I set the size of frame2 to a value.  When I put the optionmenu in that frame, the frame expands to taller than and narrower than i originally set it to.

Comment: In the big picture, I'm trying to make a widget that consists of 3 listboxes, where each item in the 3 listboxes is selectable using an optionmenu.  when a user clicks on one of the listboxes, I want to draw an optionmenu over the top of that item, so the user can change what's in that selection of the listbox by choosing an option in the optionmenu.  I got it working perfectly in linux yesterday, but now I'm trying to get it working the same way in windows.

Comment: The code above is an oversimplification, obviously, but the 'marker' frame is just there for reference.  'frame2' is the frame in question.  On linux (in kde, i haven't tried gnome) the Optionmenu was scaled to fit in and not exceed the size of frame2.  On windows the optionmenu is bigger than the size I set frame2 to be.

Comment: You can make it so that the optionmenu does not make the frame bigger, but all that is going to happen is that part of it will get chopped off. It won't magically scale to a smaller size.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.  Not sure why it was different on my linux box at home.  I found a work-around (using a ttk widget and making the font smaller so it fits) so I have something that works now on windows...thanks for the help.